# ROR code is not processed when I update a DIV content

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

Please, I ask your help with Ajax. I already found several solutions for this problem, but none of them worked.

Whenever I try to update a DIV content with ROR code, it shows the code, and not the result. I´m hiding the code that isn´t related to my problem to keep the question clean, and easy to understand.

On my HTML, I have this link:

```
<%= link_to 'Adicionar lançamento (+)', '#', id: "add-lancamento"  %>
```

On my JS file, I have:

```
$('#add-lancamento').click(function(event){
  $('#dialog').html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'form') ).html_safe %>");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I know the link is working because the content inside the #dialog is changing.
But the new content is:

```
<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'form').html_safe ) %>
```

I´m using "escape_javascript" and "html_safe", already changed "" for '', and I still get the same result. It shows the code without processing it. It doesn´t render the partial.

I found several solutions related to different versions of Rails, so these my system details:

```
Ruby version    1.9.3 (i386-mingw32)
RubyGems version    1.8.16
Rack version    1.4
Rails version   3.2.8
JavaScript Runtime  JScript
Active Record version   3.2.8
Action Pack version 3.2.8
Active Resource version 3.2.8
Action Mailer version   3.2.8
Active Support version  3.2.8
Middleware  
ActionDispatch::Static
Rack::Lock
#<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x39fdc08>
Rack::Runtime
Rack::MethodOverride
ActionDispatch::RequestId
Rails::Rack::Logger
ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
ActionDispatch::Reloader
ActionDispatch::Callbacks
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
ActiveRecord::QueryCache
ActionDispatch::Cookies
ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
ActionDispatch::Flash
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
ActionDispatch::Head
Rack::ConditionalGet
Rack::ETag
ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
Application root    D:/sites/ror/buf4
Environment development
Database adapter    sqlite3
Database schema version 20121224183551
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

does your javascript file have the extension .js.erb? assuming you're using the asset pipeline, to be able to do this

```
<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => 'form') ).html_safe %>
```

inside your javascript file requires if has an .js.erb extension

Comment: It worked! I spent almost 5 hours trying to solve it, and the solution was so simple... Thank you very much!